# How do I capture the modification of a DataContext's object's property using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm, .net-4.0

I have a WPF page which has a DataContext assigned to it. On this page it has a couple textboxes. Each textbox is bound to a property of a parent object from the DataContext. For instance, the DataContext has a Location object on it. The Location object has properties like "Name" and "Address1" etc.

The textbox controls are bound like this:

```
<Binding Path="Location.Name" Mode="TwoWay">
```

I have a "Commit" button that only becomes enabled once all the data is valid. This relies on the evaluation of this process after a property is set. If this wasn't a sub property of Location, I could easily do it like this:

```
public Location Location
{
    get { return _location; }
    set
    {
        _location = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Location");
        OnPropertyChanged("IsCommitEnabled");
    }
}
```

But since the Location object is never actually set, but rather the Location object's "Name" property, that event never fires. Is there a way to fire off my "OnPropertyChanged("IsCommitEnabled")" method when a property of my Location object is modified/set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your button has a Click handler and its Enabled property is bound to IsCommitEnabled.  Which is fine except that you are responsible for the update of the enabled state - which is the problem you expressed.
An alternative would be to replace the Click handler and Enabled binding with a binding to a Command.
You can impliment the Command either as a RoutedCommand and set CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs.CanExecute to IsCommitEnable or you could provide an implimentation of ICommand where ICommand.CanExecute will check IsCommitEnabled.
In both these case **the framework looks after polling the CanExecute method - so you dont have to do a proptry update when the property changes**.

RoutedCommand example:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding
        Command="{x:Static p:Window1.StartButtonCommand}"
        Executed="buttonStart_Executed"
        CanExecute="CommandBinding_StartButtonEnabled" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

```
public static RoutedCommand StartButtonCommand = new RoutedCommand();
private void CommandBinding_StartButtonEnabled(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) {
    e.CanExecute = ....;
}
```